# ¿Cómo coloco colores aleatoriamente a filas en una tabla pero por agrupación?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente sólo genero los colores aleatoriamente pero no se como repetir el color para un grupo de un mismo número.

**Lo que llevo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabla").append(tabla());
});

function tabla() {
  var procesos = "<table class='table table-hover'><tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Tiempo Teórico</th></tr>";
  var texto = "";
  $(datos).each(function(i, j) {
    var fondo = random_color('hex');
    var frente = invertColor(fondo);
    procesos += "<tr style='background-color: " + fondo + "; color: " + frente + ";'>";
    procesos += "<td>" + j.p + "</td>";
    procesos += "<td>" + j.tiempo_teorico + "</td>";
    procesos += "</tr>";
  });
  procesos += "</table>";
  return procesos;
};

var datos = [{
    "p": "Mezcla",
    "tiempo_teorico": "8:25:02",
    "grupo": 1
  },
  {
    "p": "Fileteado Jeje",
    "tiempo_teorico": "16:50:05",
    "grupo": 0
  },
  {
    "p": "Llenado",
    "tiempo_teorico": "1:40:05",
    "grupo": 2
  },
  {
    "p": "Vaciado",
    "tiempo_teorico": "9:02:00",
    "grupo": 1
  }
];

function random_color(format) {
  var rint = Math.floor(0x100000000 * Math.random());
  switch (format) {
    case 'hex':
      return '#' + ('00000' + rint.toString(16)).slice(-6).toUpperCase();
    case 'hexa':
      return '#' + ('0000000' + rint.toString(16)).slice(-8).toUpperCase();
    case 'rgb':
      return 'rgb(' + (rint & 255) + ',' + (rint >> 8 & 255) + ',' + (rint >> 16 & 255) + ')';
    case 'rgba':
      return 'rgba(' + (rint & 255) + ',' + (rint >> 8 & 255) + ',' + (rint >> 16 & 255) + ',' + (rint >> 24 & 255) / 255 + ')';
    default:
      return rint;
  }
}

function invertColor(hexTripletColor) {
  var color = hexTripletColor;
  color = color.substring(1); // remove #
  color = parseInt(color, 16); // convert to integer
  color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color; // invert three bytes
  color = color.toString(16); // convert to hex
  color = ("000000" + color).slice(-6); // pad with leading zeros
  color = "#" + color; // prepend #
  return color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10" id="tabla"></div>
```

**Resultado esperado:**

Como en el ejemplo que coloco, *Mezcla* y *Vaciado* pertenecen al mismo grupo (1), deberían de tener el mismo color de fondo.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10" id="tabla">
  <table class='table table-hover'>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Tiempo Teórico</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style='background-color: #E47C88; color: #1b8377;'>
      <td>Mezcla</td>
      <td>8:25:02</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='background-color: #CC582F; color: #33a7d0;'>
      <td>Fileteado Jeje</td>
      <td>16:50:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='background-color: #808E85; color: #7f717a;'>
      <td>Llenado</td>
      <td>1:40:05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='background-color: #E47C88; color: #1b8377;'>
      <td>Vaciado</td>
      <td>9:02:00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes generar los colores aleatorios e insertarlos en un `Array` (dependiendo del número de grupos que tengas) y después usar dichos colores tomando como `index` del `Array` el grupo de cada una de las filas. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo para que entiendas el concepto:

```js
var datos = [
  {
    "p": "Mezcla",
    "tiempo_teorico": "8:25:02",
    "grupo": 1
  },
  {
    "p": "Fileteado Jeje",
    "tiempo_teorico": "16:50:05",
    "grupo": 0
  },
  {
    "p": "Llenado",
    "tiempo_teorico": "1:40:05",
    "grupo": 2
  },
  {
    "p": "Vaciado",
    "tiempo_teorico": "9:02:00",
    "grupo": 1
  }
];

// Generar un color
function grc () {
  var hex = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 255))).toString(16);
  var ceros = "00";
  return ceros.slice(0, -hex.length) + hex;
}

// Generar un color RGB
function getRandomHex () {
  return "#" + grc() + grc() + grc();
}

// Generar los colores del array
function getColors () {

  var array = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    array[i] = getRandomHex();
  }
  
  return array;

}

// Insertar las filas
var colors = getColors();
var container = $("#container tbody");

datos.forEach(function (item) {

  var row = $("<tr/>");
  var td1 = $("<td/>");
  var td2 = $("<td/>");
  
  row.css({"background": colors[item.grupo], "color": colors[item.grupo]});
    
  td1.html("<span>" + item.p + "</span>");
  td2.html("<span>" + item.tiempo_teorico + "</span>");  
  
  row.append(td1, td2);
  container.append(row);

});
```

```css
#container {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#container tr {
  height: 30px;
}

#container td {
  padding: 5px;
}

#container tr span {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  -moz-filter: invert(100%);
  -o-filter: invert(100%);
  -ms-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="container">
  <thead>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Tiempo teórico</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sencillo y da la solución exacta! gracias hermano!

Comment: De nada amigo. Me alegro que te haya sido de ayuda. Un saludo.